# What does "Overflow evaluating the requirement" mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: recursion, rust

I'm running into what is [potentially a compiler bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23707). However, I don't understand the issue well enough to port the proposed solution to my own code. Here's a stripped-down version of my code:

```
struct Node {
    pub children: Vec<Node>,
}

fn map_nodes<F, R>(f: F, n: &Node) -> Vec<R>
where
    F: Fn(&Node) -> R,
{
    let mut v: Vec<R> = Vec::new();
    v.push(f(n));

    v.extend(n.children.iter().flat_map(|child| map_nodes(&f, &child)));

    v
}

fn main() {
    let node = Node {
        children: vec![Node { children: vec![] }, Node { children: vec![] }],
    };

    println!("Node lengths: {:?}", map_nodes(|n| n.children.len(), &node));
}
```

Specifically the error for this code is:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `[closure@src/main.rs:22:46: 22:66]: std::ops::Fn<(&Node,)>`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="128"]` attribute to your crate
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Fn<(&Node,)>` for `&[closure@src/main.rs:22:46: 22:66]`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Fn<(&Node,)>` for `&&[closure@src/main.rs:22:46: 22:66]`
  # ... this continues for many lines ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is an incompatibility, (which I'll show how to resolve) between unique closure types, how generics are instantiated when Rust is compiled, and a recursive use of the closure.

```
fn map_nodes<F, R>(f: F, n: &Node) -> Vec<R>
where
    F: Fn(&Node) -> R,
```

Each recursive call instantiates a new version of this function, with a new type inserted for `F`. In this case, the `map_nodes` receives `F` and passes on `&F`, and it creates an infinite series of new `map_nodes` specializations that would need to be compiled.

What you can do instead is use a concrete closure type by using a reference to a `Fn` trait object:

```
fn map_nodes<R>(f: &Fn(&Node) -> R, n: &Node) -> Vec<R>
```

This would require inserting a `&` before the lambda expression where the closure is used: `map_nodes(&|n| n.children.len(), &node)`.

If you don't want to burden your public API with this difference, then you can use an internal wrapper for your recursive function instead:

```
fn map_nodes<F, R>(f: F, n: &Node) -> Vec<R>
where
    F: Fn(&Node) -> R,
{
    fn map_nodes_inner<R>(f: &Fn(&Node) -> R, n: &Node) -> Vec<R> {
        let mut v: Vec<R> = Vec::new();
        v.push(f(n));

        v.extend(n.children.iter().flat_map(|child| map_nodes_inner(f, &child)));

        v
    }

    map_nodes_inner(&f, n)
}
```

Comment: The question is open for 3 hours, and we answer it within 26 seconds. Stack Overflow is *weird*.

Comment: Tell me about it... how do I go about picking an answer now?

Comment: I may be biased, but :-) pick this one, since it explains the reason (how rust compiles generic items).

Answer (score 7):

I don't claim to fully understand the problem, but it looks like an issue with resolving a type parameter. For example, what does `F` correspond to? At the first level, it is the closure. At the next level, it's a reference to that closure. At the **next** level, it's a reference to the reference of the closure.

My *guess* is that this is happening because of inlining, and basically it has hit an infinite recursion.

You can fix it by passing a reference to your closure instead:

```
struct Node {
    pub children: Vec<Node>,
}

fn map_nodes<F, R>(f: &F, n: &Node) -> Vec<R>
where
    F: Fn(&Node) -> R,
{
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    let z: R = f(n);
    v.push(z);

    v.extend(n.children.iter().flat_map(|child| map_nodes(f, &child)));

    v
}

fn main() {
    let node = Node {
        children: vec![Node { children: vec![] }, Node { children: vec![] }],
    };

    println!(
        "Node lengths: {:?}",
        map_nodes(&|n| n.children.len(), &node)
    );
}
```

Comment: I didn't know there was a closure-reference literal! Very cool.

Comment: @user12341234: You can use `&` to take the address of any expression. If the expression is a literal or a temporary, the compiler will silently create a temporary, anonymous binding (variable) for the expression and drop the value at the end of the statement.