# Reached the type-length limit while instantiating std::vec::IntoIter<i32>

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a `Tree` structure, but I keep getting an error whenever I try to run the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let tree = Tree::create(1, |_| Vec::new());
    println!("{:?}", tree);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tree<T> {
    value: T,
    children: Vec<Tree<T>>,
}

impl<T> Tree<T> {
    fn create<F>(value: T, get_children: F) -> Tree<T>
    where
        F: Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>,
    {
        let children = get_children(&value);
        Tree {
            value,
            children: children
                .into_iter()
                .map(|x| Tree::create(x, |y| get_children(y)))
                .collect(),
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
error: reached the type-length limit while instantiating `<std::vec::IntoIter<i32> as std::iter::Iterator>::map::<Tree<i32...`
  |
  = note: consider adding a `#![type_length_limit="2097152"]` attribute to your crate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a recursive call when creating `Tree<T>`:

```
impl<T> Tree<T> {
    fn create<F>(value: T, get_children: F) -> Tree<T>
    //...
    //...
        .map(|x| Tree::create(x, |y| get_children(y))) //endless recursive call
```

> I'm confused why it infinitely recursed since I returned an empty
>   vector in the closure.

This error occurs during compilation and the error says that `reached the type-length limit while instantiating...`. This means you are generating an enormously long type.

### How does it happen?

When you call `Tree::create(x, |y| get_children(y))` you are creating an argument closure which calls an existing closure. This is okay, but when you call it recursively the compiler will not able to detect the type of `F` at the most inner call.

Remember `get_children` has a type `F` where `F: Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>`. 
When you call `Tree::create` for the first time, `F` in `create<F>` will be inferred like this:

```
let tree = Tree::create(1, |_| Vec::new());
//inference of F: Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>
```

After the second call in `map(...)` :

```
Tree::create(x, |y| get_children(y))
//inference of F: Fn(&T) -> Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>
```

Then it will eventually turn into this:

```
//inference of F: Fn(&T)-> Fn(&T) -> Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>
//inference of F: Fn(&T)-> ... -> Fn(&T) -> Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>
```

At the end, the compiler reaches the type-length limit.

### Solution with recursion

As an addition to [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53989709/155423), you can use [function pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html):

```
impl<T> Tree<T> {
    fn create(value: T, get_children: fn(&T) -> Vec<T>) -> Tree<T> {
        let children = get_children(&value);
        Tree {
            value,
            children: children
                .into_iter()
                .map(|x| Tree::create(x, get_children))
                .collect(),
        }
    }
}
```

### Solution without recursion

You can fix the issue by sending the function to `Vec<Tree<T>>` as `get_children` instead of generating in `create`, like this:

```
fn main() {
    let inner_tree = Tree::create(1, |_| Vec::new());
    let tree = Tree::create(1, move |_| vec![inner_tree]);
    println!("{:?}", tree);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tree<T> {
    value: T,
    children: Vec<Tree<T>>,
}

impl<T> Tree<T> {
    fn create<F>(value: T, get_children: F) -> Tree<T>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&T) -> Vec<Tree<T>>,
    {
        let children = get_children(&value);
        Tree { value, children }
    }
}
```

Please notice that I changed the function parameter's type from `Fn` to `FnOnce`. It is needed to move ownership of inner trees into a closure. It is going to be called once so it can consume the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The recursion was intentional — I was hoping to take a tree like structure (such as a DOM tree) and wrap it in a formal tree structure so I can add methods to map, fold, etc. I'm confused why it infinitely recursed since I returned an empty vector in the closure.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. The error message makes much more sense now. So is what I'm trying to achieve not possible?

Comment: @AdamPutinski I wasn't able to response back, edited answer again, i hope it helps you more.

Comment: @Shepmaster is that needed for this case ?

Comment: For the simple example given by the OP, no. However, it's not hard [to imagine a case where it's desired](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b66a18107ff0b773a115404eb6b0ef91).

Comment: @Shepmaster Indeed, but  imo expected argument which called get_children should just get the children. Mutable behavior is a bad design for this case despite i was just trying to add conciseness to your code(where you were using **Immutable Fn**) .

Comment: I disagree that mutable is bad design here; you simply cannot make such a broad proclamation. It's certainly within an API designers right to make that choice, but the Rust standard library has had multiple cases where people used `Fn` and retroactively realized that they should have used `FnMut`. You are right that my original answer used `Fn`; I followed the OPs lead. I have since changed that. Additionally, a function pointer removes [the ability for **immutable state** as well](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8fbaf9aa0f66423fac8863ade15fc06b).

Comment: @Shepmaster It was certainly not a broad proclamation, it was an opinion that points **get_children** should get the children without mutating. I also never wrote: use `fn` instead of `Fn`, like you said the API designers right to make that choice.It is also valid for deciding what to use  `fn` or `Fn`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same underlying problem as [What does "Overflow evaluating the requirement" mean and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31196422/155423) and can be solved the same way. This means you avoid the type-level recursion by using a reference trait object:

```
impl<T> Tree<T> {
    fn create(value: T, mut get_children: impl FnMut(&T) -> Vec<T>) -> Tree<T> {
        fn create_inner<T>(value: T, get_children: &mut FnMut(&T) -> Vec<T>) -> Tree<T> {
            let children = get_children(&value)
                .into_iter()
                .map(|x| create_inner(x, get_children))
                .collect();

            Tree { value, children }
        }

        create_inner(value, &mut get_children)
    }
}
```

I've also switched from `Fn` to `FnMut`, as its better to be more flexible with closure types when possible.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful!